# Finding Google Apis Script ID

Tags: c#, .net, google-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I'm trying to create a **.NET** program with Google Sheet API.
I read [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/rest/quickstart/dotnet#step_3_set_up_the_sample) and followed the steps, however, I found this line

> Be sure to also replace the placeholder ENTER_YOUR_SCRIPT_ID_HERE with the script ID of your target script.

**I have no idea what scriptID is**. Could someone please help me to find the ScriptID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick search gave these results.

Under General Procedure, [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/rest/api#general_procedure):

> Deploy the script project for execution by selecting Publish > Deploy as API executable. Choose a version (or create a new one) and who has access, then click Deploy. The new dialog that opens will show your script's ID, listed under "Current API ID". Make note of this ID — you will need to enter it into the application code so that the API knows which script to call. If you need to find it again later, select Publish > Deploy as API executable in the code editor to see it.

also [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/execution/rest/v1/scripts/run#path-parameters)

> scriptId - The project key of the script to be executed. To find the project key, open the project in the **script editor**, then select **File > Project > properties**.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It will be referring to a ID on https://console.developers.google.com I just cannot figure out which one. There is a project ID and a credential ID that I can see. Perhaps try both of these? I have created applications in .NET using the drive API and have never needed a scriptID before.